# i18next - " WebpackError: TypeError: namespaces.forEach is not a function" (hooks)

Tags: javascript, namespaces, internationalization, gatsby, i18next

I'm trying to get `i18next` to work in my Gatsby project but I keep running into the below error whenever i try to build using `yarn build`.

From my `package.json`:

```json
"i18next": "^19.8.2",
"react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
```

My `i18n/index.js` file:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
// ...

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  fallbackLng: "en",
  // have a common namespace used around the full app
  ns: ["translations"],
  defaultNS: "translations",
  wait: true,
  useSuspense: false
}, (err, t) => {
  i18n.t('en');
});

// load additional namespaces after initialization
i18n.loadNamespaces('translations', (err, t) => {
  i18n.t('i18n', { lng: 'en' } );
});

// i18n resource bundles for views
const i18nResourceBundlesViews = [
  {
    intro: {
      en: { ...intro.en },
      ja: { ...intro.ja },
    },
  },
  // ...
];

// i18n resource bundles for components
const i18nResourceBundlesComponents = [
  {
    header: {
      en: { ...header.en },
      ja: { ...header.ja },
    },
  },
  {
    footer: {
      en: { ...footer.en },
      ja: { ...footer.ja },
    },
  },
];

// Load i18n resource bundles from each resource object
const getI18nResourceBundles = (resource) => {
  const key = Object.keys(resource)[0];
  const enBundle = resource[key].en;
  const jaBundle = resource[key].ja;
  // English translations
  i18n.addResourceBundle('en', key, enBundle);
  // Japanese translations
  i18n.addResourceBundle('ja', key, jaBundle);
};

// i18n resource bundles for views
i18nResourceBundlesViews.forEach((resource) => {
  getI18nResourceBundles(resource);
});

// i18n resource bundles for components
i18nResourceBundlesComponents.forEach((resource) => {
  getI18nResourceBundles(resource);
});

export default i18n;
```

The full error message after `yarn build`

```sh
❯ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ gatsby build
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.044s
success load plugins - 0.800s
success onPreInit - 0.016s
success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.027s
success initialize cache - 0.009s
success copy gatsby files - 0.154s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.020s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.007s
success source and transform nodes - 1.225s
success building schema - 0.415s
success createPages - 0.021s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.104s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.002s
success update schema - 0.052s
success extract queries from components - 0.418s
success write out requires - 0.008s
success write out redirect data - 0.005s
warn The icon(./static/favicon/favicon-512.png) you provided to 'gatsby-plugin-manifest' is not square.
The icons we generate will be square and for the best results we recommend you provide a square icon.

success Build manifest and related icons - 0.183s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.192s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 6.260 s
⠀
warn Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 19.520s
success Rewriting compilation hashes - 0.010s
success run queries - 20.490s - 6/6 0.29/s
failed Building static HTML for pages - 4.770s

 ERROR #95313

Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  37 |       var _this = this;
  38 |
> 39 |       namespaces.forEach(function (ns) {
     | ^
  40 |         if (!_this.usedNamespaces[ns]) _this.usedNamespaces[ns] = true;
  41 |       });
  42 |     }


  WebpackError: TypeError: namespaces.forEach is not a function

  - context.js:39 ReportNamespaces.addUsedNamespaces
    node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/context.js:39:1

  - useTranslation.js:41 useTranslation
    node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/useTranslation.js:41:1

  - index.jsx:27 Footer
    src/components/theme/Footer/index.jsx:27:38


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

In my `Footer/index.jsx` where the error originally occurs (line 27):

```js
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation({useSuspense: false});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

Reference including the solution: https://github.com/benji011/portfolio.benjaminlo.io/pull/9#issuecomment-707612060

> I think I've managed to pinpoint the two issues you were originally
> having. I've uploaded the fixes I've made, please see if it builds for
> you. It builds fine for me.
>
> ### 1. React suspense:
>
> i18n appears to use Suspense but this is problematic for Gatsby. See
> [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20371).
>
> The fix is quite straightforward and I've added it to the config.
>
> ### 2. The `i18ncheck` statement: ```const i18nCheck = i18n.languages.toLowerCase().includes('en') ||
>
> i18n.languages.toLowerCase().includes('en-');```
>
> This statement is problematic.
>
> There are two variables that contain the languages.
>
> 1. `language`, which I think is the current language, and is set to a string: `en`
> 2. `languages` which is an array of languages. This is set to `['en', 'dev']`.
>
> If you want to check for the array `languages`, then we can't use
> `toLowerCase()` like it was used. It will result in an error as we are
> applying `toLowerCase()` on the entire array and not an element of the
> array. `toLowerCase()` must be used on a string and won't ork on an
> array. We would have to loop through the array and then apply
> `toLowerCase()`. I don't think you were wanting to check the array
> though as the language, for example 'en', would always be in the
> array.
>
> Another issue related to this is that `i18n` might not have the
> property yet, so we need to check that it has the property first.
>
> The best approach, imo, is to just check the `language` to see if it
> is `en` or `en-`.
>
> ### Regarding ESLint and Prettier:
>
> You should use both.
>
> ESLint is a linter and will show code errors. The project already has
> an ESLint config, you just need the plugin. There might be a window
> that pops up when you open the project, which you must then choose
> `Allow`.
>
> Prettier is a formatter and will format your code e.g. split up a long
> line into 3 separate lines